# Avoiding Google+ Sign in button

Tags: android, webview, google-oauth

I am new to android development and I am trying to build an android app on eclipse that will let its users share/post to google+. I am following https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in to implement it but once the user has signed in their account is tied to the device. I want my app to ask for google credintials everytime the users want to share on google+. I am thinking of doing it using a webview but I have no idea how to do it, I have also searched a lot of document but couldn't find anything that does it step by step. Please help.

Comment: Does that work very well for the user experience? Such third party designs are generally like that for a reason

Comment: Yes the Google+ sign in button is very convenient for the user because it is secure and they don't have to put in the account information again and again. But the app that I am making will be installed in a public device therefore I have to let the users sign in every time they use the app.